# Why does the Youtube API remove local div and add its own?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on a youtube search engine. Everything works okay on the back end but I have hit a wall because Youtube adds a div like so:

```
<div class="item">

</div>
```

Around the video and removes my div. I have no way of pin pointing why this happens but I have read from other threads that this is not the first time someone has encountered a problem like this.

It would be much appreciated if you could help out!!

Answer (score 0):

make another div - a 'victim' which the YT script would 'eat' and would leave what you need. For example, now you have:

```
<div id='pagewrapper'>

  <div id='DivForYouTube'>
  </div>

</div>
```

let's say you need to save 'DivForYouTube' and now YouTube destroys it and sets its own.
So my idea would be to create another (victim) div, which YouTube would eat and the neede one - would rest.

```
<div id='pagewrapper'>

  <div id='DivForYouTube'>
       <div id='specialVictimDivWhereYouSetYouTube'>
       </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

What whould you say?